# How to add dynamic parameters from for loop to @Query

Tags: jquery, sql, spring-boot

I have a query like this:

```
StringBuilder sql= new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT
//
//
 "AND 10000 * A.HAYTZY + 100 * A.HAYTZA + A.HAYTZG BETWEEN "
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            sql.append(" (A.HAYPTP = " + arrayList.get(i).getProductCode() +
                    " AND A.HAYFOR = " + arrayList.get(i).getProductSubCode() + ") OR ");
        }
        sql.append(" (1 = 2))");
```

So, in repository, I have to query it.

Like here:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-named-parameters.html

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.dept = :dept AND "
          + "(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e2.salary) FROM Employee e2 "
          + "WHERE e.salary < e2.salary AND e2.dept = :dept) < :topSalNum "
          + "ORDER BY e.salary DESC")
  List<Employee> findByDeptTopNSalaries(@Param("topSalNum") long topSalaryNum, @Param("dept") String dept);
```

So, for my query, can i do something like this?

```
  "SELECT DISTINCT
        //
        //
         "AND 10000 * A.HAYTZY + 100 * A.HAYTZA + A.HAYTZG BETWEEN :forLoop
                sql.append(" (1 = 2))"
          List<Object> getObjects(@Param("forLoop") String forLoop);
```

And from service i do this to call this query:

```
String forLoop =  for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            forLoop .append(" (A.HAYPTP = " + arrayList.get(i).getProductCode() +
                    " AND A.HAYFOR = " + arrayList.get(i).getProductSubCode() + ") OR ");
        }

repo.getObjects(forLoop );
```

Comment: No you can't. For your requirement using Criteria API would be appropriate. Take a look at Spring Data JPA Specifications https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: @SimonMartinelli do i have a proper entity for Criteria, because there are no entities, only objects for that query.

Comment: I don't understand. You have entites: Employee

Comment: @SimonMartinelli that was from the URL to show example.  My query goes to at least 8 different tables. A big query

Comment: And it's an SQL query?=

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes. The query in the beginning of the question is that query but middle of it cropped.